# Aggregate Customer Order Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Consider the following database tables and contents:

```
CustomerType     
CustomerTypeId  CustomerTypeDisplayName
1   Individual
2   Organisation

Customer         
CustomerId  CustomerName    CustomerTypeId
1   John Smith  1
2   Peterson Ltd    2
3   Paul Taylor 1
4   Janet Peters    1

Order        
OrderId CustomerId  OrderDate
1   1   2010-01-01
2   4   2010-01-02
3   2   2010-01-02
4   2   2010-02-10
5   2   2010-03-05
6   1   2011-10-01
7   4   2011-11-01
8   2   2012-05-01
```

Given the database above please write a SQL query that would return the data in the following format:

```
CustomerName    CustomerTypeDisplayName NumberOfOrders  EarliestOrderDate
John Smith  Individual  2   2010-01-01
```

…   …   …   …

Comment: what have your tried? It is more fun if you do it on your own.

Comment: you are not really learning when you just ask for answers and people give you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query shall written you the data in required format as in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/1OgStJLx).

```
SELECT 
  c.CustomerName, 
  ct.CustomerTypeDisplayName, 
  COUNT(o.OrderId) AS NumberOfOrders, 
  MIN(o.OrderDate) AS EarliestOrderDate
FROM Customer c
JOIN CustomerType ct ON c.CustomerTypeId = ct.CustomerTypeId
LEFT JOIN [Order] o ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
GROUP BY 
  c.CustomerName, 
  ct.CustomerTypeDisplayName;
```

Please make sure to surround `order` table_name with square brackets as `[order]` as order is a reserved keyword in sql server.

The above query shall give you result as :

```
CustomerName    CustomerTypeDisplayName     NumberOfOrders      EarliestOrderDate
Janet Peters    Individual                  2                   2010-01-02
John Smith      Individual                  2                   2010-01-01
Paul Taylor     Individual                  0                   null
Peterson Ltd    Organisation                4                   2010-01-02
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd aggregate the orders and then join them on the customers:

```sql
SELECT CustomerName, CustomerTypeDisplayName, NumberOfOrders, EarliestOrderDate
FROM   Customer c
JOIN   CustomerType ct ON c.CustomerTypeId = ct.CustomerTypeId
JOIN   (SELECT   CustomerId, 
                 COUNT(*) AS NumberOfOrders,
                 MIN(OrderDate) AS EarliestOrderDate
        FROM     Orders
        GROUP BY CustomerID) o ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
```